# Drupal - Print Database Output to custom block

Tags: drupal, module, foreach, block

I created a little module with the DB fields "`tag`", "`tag_url`" and "`tag_weight`" and a form to fill them up.

Now I want to output the DB values in a custom block, but I dont know how to create it the correct way :-/

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_block_info().
     *
     * This hook declares what blocks are provided by the module.
     */
    function myModule_block_info() {
        $blocks['example_uppercase'] = array(
            // info: The name of the block.
            'info' => t('Example: uppercase this please'),
            'status' => TRUE,
        );
        return $blocks;
    }

    /**
     * Implements hook_block_view().
     *
     * This hook generates the contents of the blocks themselves.
     */
    function myModule_block_view($delta = '') {
        //The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested. 
        switch ($delta) {
            case 'example_uppercase':
                    //Select items from DB
                $result = db_select('myModule','ht')
                    ->fields('ht',array('tag','tag_url','tag_weight'))
                    ->execute();
                    **$block['content'] = foreach($result as $value) { echo $value->tag; }**
                break;
        }
        return $block;
    }
```

When I am trying to do this, I get:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in
>   /.module on line 49

How to print out the database values to the block?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that i need to do it that way:

https://drupal.org/node/1104498